# Wrap Div around WP Posts / Pages function

Tags: wordpress

I need a function for wordpress as I need to wrap a div around page / post titles.

The title looks like this:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">Test post</h1>
```

So I need to do something like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <h1 class="entry-title">Test post</h1>
</div>
```

Any ideas if how I could so this?

Comment: Just edit your theme's file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this correct way, you need add filter. enter following code in function.php or your plugin page:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'title_div_wrapper');
function title_div_wrapper($title) {
    $title = '<div id="mydiv">
           <h1 class="entry-title">'.$title.'</h1>
        </div>';

    return $title;
}
```

Now default the_title() will output post title with div wrap.

For more detail, read wordpress documentation mention by @bodi0

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your output with custom function. Place this code in your theme's `function.php` file:

```
if (!function_exists('filter_function_h1')) {
 function filter_function_h1( $content ) {
        // Wrap a div to some content
        $content = '<div id="mydiv">'. $content.'</div>';  

    // Returns the content.
    return $content;
 }
}
```

Then, in your page template, or whenever you have to show wrapped post titles, use this function like this:

`filter_function_h1('Your h1 tag content here');`

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. I need to add it on a plugin so would have to use the add_action() ... How would I do this with this function?

Comment: Use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter and https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content